# Changes of coordinates in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

I'm taking an undergraduate differential geometry class, and because either because the professor has chosen to forgo rigor (as a background in analysis isn't required and most of the class has negligible proof-writing experience) or else because I'm just not getting it, I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding the way he discusses changes of coordinates.

This is the general description he gives:

If we change local coordinates from $\{x^1, ..., x^i, ... x^n\} $ to $\{\hat{x}^1, ..., \hat{x}^{\alpha},..., \hat{x}^n\}$ by the map $F$, the vector field $U = u^iX_i$ to $\hat{U} = \hat{u}^{\alpha}\hat{X}_{\alpha}$

$\hat{U} = DF(U)$ and $\hat{u}^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial \hat{x}^{\alpha}}{\partial x^i}u^i$

I understand (I think) what all the symbols mean, and I'm comfortable with Einstein summation convention, and the idea of a derivative map (again, at an unrigorous, undergrad level). **That said, I cannot for the life of me understand why if the coordinates transform under $F$, why the vector transforms under $DF$.**

I would like a) some intuition about this (if there's an intuitive way to view it) and b) a way to show that this is true (if there's a straightforward, fairly elementary way to show it).

Thanks!

Comment: too much notation and nothing concrete. What is your question?

Comment: you do not say what $x^i$-s mean, you do not tell why you change your coordinates, as much as what is $X$, what your operator $F$ is, etc, your $DF(U)$ expression... How one can help?

Comment: Seems pretty unambiguous to me. If you'd like me to go through and give more definitions, I'm happy to do so. I understood that these were common notations in differential geometry, but perhaps not. As for what my question is, it's bolded. Shouldn't be too difficult to read

Comment: Well, no. The notation is 50% of all problems in math and I do not understand what you mean with yours. So, I cannot understand your bold question. In general: if $F$ transforms coordinates, then $DF$ as a composition should also do  that.

Comment: @BenL I was recently told to make up my own notation for differential geometry because there were essentially no real standards. I certainly haven't done enough reading on the subject myself to say but it was advice from a well credentialed source so I assume there was some truth to it.

Comment: well, as you wish. As I said, I cannot help you. The best question is a question with a minimum of notation. If you change a basis, all vectors will be measured in that new basis.

Comment: Well if you don't know what your own notation means well enough to explain it to others I recommend you start there. The problem will likely remain intractable until you know what the symbols mean.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, no one told me it was standard, it just seemed like a reasonable (if not true) assumption, as my professor is an important figure in the field at an Ivy League university. And I know exactly what the symbols mean; if they are standard than defining them isn't necessary, and as I believed them to be so, you can come up with kinder explanations for why I didn't write down extensive definitions than "I don't know what my own notation means". Thanks

Comment: @BenL I did respond kindly. You said you were incapable of explaining it which strongly implies ignorance of the notation.  If you misrepresented your ability to avoid doing the necessary work then say so instead of making baseless assumptions and pushing the burden onto others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't really specified enough to be able to answer this precisely. I will assume that your manifold $M$ is embedded in $\mathbf{R}^n$ for some $n$, since that is the typical assumption at this level. One has from calculus, or multivariable analysis that given a smooth map $F:\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^m$, there is an induced linear transformation $DF_p:\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^m$. This is usually called the total derivative of the map. (See Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis*, for instance.) $DF_p$ has matrix representation given by the so-called Jacobian matrix. If we think of $F=(F_1,\ldots, F_m)$, then
$$ J(F)_p=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1}(p)&\cdots&\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n}(p)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_1}(p)&\cdots&\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_1}(p)
\end{bmatrix}.$$
The idea, is that this map is a linear transformation of tangent spaces. $DF_p: T_p\mathbf{R}^n\to T_{F(p)}\mathbf{R}^m$. In this case, since we are in Euclidean space, we have that the tangent space at $p$ is identified with $\mathbf{R}^n$ itself, so we view this transformation as simply going from $\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^m$ with no loss of precision. Now, if we have two coordinate charts on $M\subset \mathbf{R}^n$ given by $\mathbf{x}:U\to \mathbf{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{y}:V\to \mathbf{R}^n$, we have that $\mathbf{y}\circ \mathbf{x}^{-1}:\mathbf{x}(U\cap V)\to \mathbf{y}(U\cap V)$ is a smooth map of Euclidean spaces. As such, we can compute its Jacobian. Here, $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ and $\mathbf{y}=(y_1,\ldots, y_n)$ can be thought of as your coordinate systems in your notation. There are some minor details missing. But, the idea is that this transformation also acts as a map $T_pM\to T_pM$ for $p\in U\cap V$.

Anyway, if you compute the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation of your change of coordinates, you will find that it is of the form
$$ J(\mathbf{y}\circ \mathbf{x}^{-1})_p=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1}(p)&\cdots&\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n}(p)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_1}(p)&\cdots&\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_n}(p)
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Fine, so how does this work in vector field world? I'm uncertain as to what definition of vector field you are using. However, let's just think of a vector field $X$ on $M$ as a linear combination of the form
$$ X_p=\sum_{i=1}^na_i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_p$$
where the $a_i\in C^{\infty}(M)$. This just means they are smooth real valued functions on $M$. Well, now we have that $X_p$ is acted upon naturally by $J(F)_p$ by
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1}(p)&\cdots&\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n}(p)\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_1}(p)&\cdots&\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_n}(p)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1(p)\\
\vdots\\
a_n(p)
\end{bmatrix}.$$
So, we have that the vector field $X$ re-expressed in $\mathbf{y}$ coordinates is of the form
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^na_i(p)\frac{\partial y_j}{\partial x_i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\bigg|_p.$$
This is, I believe, everything you were trying to show.

Comment: That's very helpful! The issue I'm having is that it's not clear why we're saying that we use the $J(y\circ  x^{-1}$ to express a vector field in different coordinates, and not simply $y\circ x^{-1}$. If I understand correctly the Jacobian is a map between tangent spaces, but you indicate above that $y \circ x^{-1}$ serves this function as well?

Comment: $y\circ x^{-1}$ is the coordinate transformation. It induces a linear map of tangent spaces, the total derivative, which has matrix representation given by $J$. The point is that vector fields live in the tangent bundle $TM$, or more specifically, vector fields evaluated at a point live in $T_pM$, the tangent space at that point. So, to transform vector fields, we use the induced map on tangent spaces, given in coordinates by the Jacobian

Comment: Oh I see! So informally speaking, the vector field maps a point on the manifold to a vector in the tangent space of that point? If that's so, then you're right, we'd except $J$ to to transform the vector field.

Comment: In fact, formally a vector field is an association sending points on the manifold to tangent vectors in their tangent spaces. $X:M \to T_pM$ by $X: p\mapsto X_p.$

Comment: Sorry, as an edit to the above, $:M\to TM$.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis sorry, shouldn't the coefficients of the vector field written in terms of $\{y^k\}_{k=1}^n$ coordinates, be multiplied by $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\vert_p$? Anyway, I found your answer really clear and useful :-)

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I myself studied differential geometry and applications of it all without a formal education. As I understand it in the notation used by Pavel Grinfeld in his book "Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces" The "map" you mentioned, $F$ is a vector function which goes from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with each component being described by $F$ so it can be represented in components as the following:
$$F^\alpha=\hat{x}^\alpha(x^i)=\hat{x}^\alpha(x)\\
\vec{F}=\hat{x}^\alpha(x)\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha$$
where $\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha$ is the basis in the $\hat{x}^\alpha$ coordinate system. Thus when we consider vector fields in the $\hat{x}^\alpha$ coordinate system, this is writ in the following format:
$$\textbf{P}'=\textbf{P}(\hat{x})$$
Since we are talking about a basis $\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha$ which is defined globally all around the space of interest, we can safely assume that
$$\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha=\frac{\partial \textbf{R}}{\partial \hat{x}^\alpha}$$
Where $\textbf{R}$ is an imaginary vector which can locate every point in the space. Expanding that definition of the basis vector, all the partial derivative means is that $\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha$ is a method of directing distances between points along the coordinate directions. (Think about it, since the partial derivative is a method of observing differences in the directions of the coordinates). Now noticing how the basis changes from coordinate system to system, we see that using the chain rule:
$$\textbf{Z}_i=\frac{\partial \textbf{R}}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial \hat{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^i}\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha$$
Now since we know that a tensor in the $\hat{x}^\alpha$ coordinate system will be represented as $\textbf{P}'=P^\alpha\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha$ we can observe the way it compares to $\textbf{P}=P^i\textbf{Z}_i$ and by making the following correspondence $\textbf{P}'=\textbf{P}$ by geometrical intuition we see that:
$$P^\alpha=\left(\frac{\partial \hat{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^i}\right)P^i$$
To finish it off, noticing that $\vec{F}$ is a 1-form, we notice that its differential is given by:
$$D\vec{F}=\frac{\partial \hat{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^i}\textbf{Z}^i\otimes\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha$$
And that indeed:
$$D\vec{F}\cdot\textbf{P}=D\vec{F}\cdot(P^j\textbf{Z}_j)=\frac{\partial \hat{x}^\alpha}{\partial x^i}P^i\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha=P^\alpha\hat{\textbf{Z}}_\alpha=\textbf{P}' $$
This is the method by which contravariant vectors transform under your coordinate change :) I hope that helped...its slightly informal and a geometrical way of doing things but it really highlights the geometrical beauty of tensor calculus I think. Good Luck!